# Why am I unable to do a "sudo apt-get update"?

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, terminal, upgrade

I recently started using linux mint. I am trying to execute the following command in my terminal  `sudo apt-get update` . But I always get this output:

How can I solve this issue?

```
...
Ign:10 http://archive.canonical.com sarah/partner all Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.canonical.com sarah/partner Translation-en_GB
Ign:12 http://archive.canonical.com sarah/partner Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com sarah Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/sarah/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list` :

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ sarah partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ sarah partner
```

Comment: _Ask Ubuntu_ is our friend: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14629/

Comment: @JdeBP please don't suggest other sites on the SE network if you aren't familiar with their scope. The OP is using Mint which is off topic on AU and their problem has nothing to do with the question you linked to.

Comment: On the contrary, as one can see from this question, it's the Canonical Partner repository that is the locus of the problem here.  And the _Ask Ubuntu_ answers there show how that is set (and even, in one answer, a likely way that "sarah" is erroneously getting in the configuration file on a Mint system instead of "xenial").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that `apt-get update` still updates its indexes as appropriate, it's just complaining that it can't download the information required for some of its repositories.

`sarah` is a Mint code-name, not an Ubuntu code-name, so it makes no sense to try to use a `sarah` repository hosted by Canonical; you can safely delete the additional repositories:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
```

This will fix the errors you're seeing.

Comment: "sarah is a Mint code-name, not an Ubuntu code-name, so it makes no sense to try to use a sarah repository" But I am using linux mint not ubuntu, shouldn't I be using it in stead of deleting it? Sorry if that s a stupid question.

Comment: You forgot the last part: "repository hosted by Canonical". That's why you should delete the repository — there's no `sarah` repository on http://archive.canonical.com/.

Answer (score -2):

There is no sarah version of ubuntu. Use linuxmint repositories only when using linuxming distribution.

Comment: How can I solve my issue? I am a beginner...